# Call to undefined function _bootstrap_process_element() in /var/www/xxxxx/includes/form.inc on line 1870

Tags: drupal

We have form having upload elements. While uploading images, we are getting error:
 Call to undefined function _bootstrap_process_element() in /var/www/events/includes/form.inc on line 1870

Can anyone help to fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you recently updated Drupal or contributed modules you will likely need to perform a registry rebuild.

```
drush rr
```

...if you have drush. Otherwise Acquia has a nice post about it here:

https://docs.acquia.com/articles/how-rebuild-drupal-7-registry